# using fontawesome in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

I have code below I want to change `+` and `-` with font-awesome `<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>` and `<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>`

```
$( ".filter-tag-group .tag-group" ).each(function( index ) {
      var check_this=this;
      $(this).find(".show_filter_content").on( 'click', function() {
        if($(this).html()=="+"){ //in here
          $(this).html("-"); //in here
          $(check_this).find(".filter-title").addClass("active");
          $(check_this).find(".filter-content").css( "display","block" );
        }
        else{
          $(this).html("+"); //in here
          $(check_this).find(".filter-title").removeClass("active");
          $(check_this).find(".filter-content").css( "display","none" );
        }
      });
    });
```

My html:

```
<span class="show_filter_content"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
<div class="row filter-content">
</div>
```

I tried myself but i did stop functioning.

Comment: how your html for the code looks like?

Comment: All you need to do is change the class of whatever element you require. You're already using the code to do this, `addClass()` and `removeClass()`, although you could use `toggleClass()` too

Comment: @G_S updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is change the class of whatever element you require. You're already using the code to do this (ie. `addClass()` and `removeClass()`) although you could simplify the logic by using `toggleClass()` instead, like this:

```js
$(".filter-tag-group .tag-group .show_filter_content").on('click', function() {
  var $icon = $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
  var $group = $icon.closest('.tag-group');
  $group.find('.filter-title').toggleClass('active');
  $group.find('.filter-content').toggle();
});
```

```css
.active { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div class="filter-tag-group">
  <div class="tag-group">
    <span class="filter-title active">Title</span>
    <span class="show_filter_content">
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </span>
    <div class="row filter-content">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it adds both classes at the same time

Comment: My bad- I updated the answer for you, and added a working example. Note for the future that it would have been more helpful to see a more complete HTML sample in your question, ie. one which included the `.filter-tag-group` and `.tag-group` elements

Answer (score 0):

You should use `addClass("fa fa-plus")` and `removeClass("fa fa-plus")`.
Same for - sign too.

Changing the HTML wouldn't change the FA icon.

Edit:
Give the icon a spesific name/class like `theIcon`.

```
<span class="show_filter_content">
   <i class="fa fa-plus theIcon"></i>
</span>
<div class="row filter-content">
</div>
```

Then

```
$( ".filter-tag-group .tag-group" ).each(function( index ) {
  var check_this=this;
  $(this).find(".show_filter_content").on( 'click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("fa-plus")){ //is it + signed?
      $(this).find(".theIcon").removeClass("fa-plus"); //we will turn this to -
      $(this).find(".theIcon").addClass("fa fa-minus"); //turn it to minus

      //the rest does stuff
      $(check_this).find(".filter-title").addClass("active");
      $(check_this).find(".filter-content").css( "display","block" );
    }
    else {
      $(this).find(".theIcon").removeClass("fa-plus"); //we will turn this to +
      $(this).find(".theIcon").addClass("fa fa-minus"); //turn it to plus

      //the rest does stuff      
      $(check_this).find(".filter-title").removeClass("active");
      $(check_this).find(".filter-content").css( "display","none" );
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: can you share complete code please? not sure where to add

Comment: it just change + to - `once` and not close or open the div

Comment: shouldn't have commented `var check_this=this;`

Answer (score 0):

Changing HTML will not help, font-awsome uses icons and not HTML text.

So, you actually need to change the classname. Use addClass() and removeClass().

You should apply this change to your code:

Instead of writing this code:

```
  if($(this).html()=="+"){ //in here
      $(this).html("-"); //in here
      $(check_this).find(".filter-title").addClass("active");
      $(check_this).find(".filter-content").css( "display","block" );
    }
    else{
      $(this).html("+"); //in here
      $(check_this).find(".filter-title").removeClass("active");
      $(check_this).find(".filter-content").css( "display","none" );
    }
```

Trye this

```
  if($(this).hasClass('fa-plus')){ //in here
      $(this).removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus);
    }
    else{
      $(this).removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide your code in jsfiddle link.. i will help